# Binding to ListView ItemsSource in a custom UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, win-universal-app

In a Windows Universal app I have a custom `UserControl` "ListControl", which contains a `ListView`. I want the `UserControl` to have a `ItemsSource` property, so that I can bind the `ListView`'s `ItemsSource` to it. I tried the following, but getting a `Value does not fall within the expected range.` xaml Exception:

In `ListControl.xaml.cs`:

```
public static DependencyProperty MyItemsSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MyItemsSource", typeof(object), typeof(ListControl), new PropertyMetadata(""));

public object MyItemsSource
{
    get { return GetValue(MyItemsSourceProperty); }
    set { SetValue(MyItemsSourceProperty, value); }
}
```

In `ListControl.xaml` (`x:Name="Control"`):

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=Control, Path=MyItemsSource}">
```

The Page that contains the control:

```
<local:ListControl MyItemsSource="{Binding Instanz.ArtikelAlle, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

The binding source:

```
private ObservableCollection<Artikel> _ArtikelAlle = new ObservableCollection<Artikel>();
public ObservableCollection<Artikel> ArtikelAlle
{
    get { return _ArtikelAlle; }
    set { _ArtikelAlle = value; SendPropertyChanged("ArtikelAlle"); }
}
```

Comment: I believe, the Control in line `<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=Control, Path=MyItemsSource}">` is name of UserControl (set through x:Name)?

Comment: Also, on which line you are getting the motioned error?

Comment: I solved the error. The problem was that one of the ObservableCollections was null. Just have the problem, that changes to the ObservableCollection are'nt shown in the View. First when I renavigate to the page, the List is updated. Do I have to do something different with UpdateSourceTrigger?

Comment: Basically, as per best practice, you should only expose the getter of collection which is bound to view. For example in your case it should be: `private ObservableCollection<Artikel> _ArtikelAlle = new ObservableCollection<Artikel>();
public ObservableCollection<Artikel> ArtikelAlle
{
    get { return _ArtikelAlle; }
}` .Now you should always work on public property and should bind to ItemSource as {Binding ArtikelAlle}